# Securing VMM Scale Set using Security Center

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set, securitycenter

I am trying to use security center for intrusion prevention of my **web front end** deployed in a **VMM scale set** behind a **WAF**. I dont't see the VMs in the **VMM scale set** under Security center blade.

How can VMs in Scale Set be protected using Azure Security Center.

Thanks